# Add an element to NSDictionary from API response

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary, nsmutabledictionary

I am sending an API request to a server, I receive the JSON response in the following format:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "example",
    "file": "http://example.com/file.png"
}
```

What i want to do is, extract the `file` element and add it to already existing NSDictionary, here is my `.h` file

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDictionary *postedContent;
```

Here i am assigning the value in `.m` file

```
self.postedContent = @{@"agent_id": agent_id, @"status_id": selectedStatusId ,@"message": comment ,@"ratingDate": currentDate };
```

Here is where i am trying to add file element to self.postedContent

```
// Retrieve file element from API response
NSError* error;
NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:returnData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
NSArray* file = [json objectForKey:@"file"];
// Add it to NSMutableDisctionary
NSMutableDictionary *notificationContent = self.postedContent;
notificationContent[@"file"] = file;
```

This does not work because `self.postedContent` is of type `NSDictionary` and `notificationContent` is of type `NSMutableDictionary`

How do i add the file element in self.postedContent, here is what i am expecting in the end

```
NSDictionary *content = @{@"agent_id": agent_id, @"status_id": selectedStatusId ,@"message": comment ,@"ratingDate": currentDate, @"file": file };
```

Where am i going wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSMutableDictionary *notificationContent = [self.postedContent mutableCopy];
notificationContent[@"file"] = file;
self.postedContent = [notificationContent copy];
```

If you do this a lot, either make postedContent an NSMutableArray, or create a protocol method.

Answer (score 2):

You are going to need to make a mutable copy of the dictionary when you assign it to the notificationContent pointer. Currently you are just assigning an immutable dictionary to the pointer. The way to do it is:

```
notificationContent = self.postedContent.mutableCopy;
```

Hope this helps.